# Replace all leading and trailing white spaces and tabs

Tags: regex, sed

My code is like below:

```
cat sample.txt

    line1    value1
line2    value2    
    line3    value3
```

My code: It is removing spaces but not able to remove tabs.

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

In POSIX world `[[:blank:]]` would match both space and tab so you can do this:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-sed answers:

```sh
perl -lpe 's/^\s*|\s*$//g' sample.txt
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < sample.txt
```

The last one is interesting: to preserve leading and trailing whitespace, you have to explicitly set IFS to the empty string. Compare

```sh
while      read -r line; do echo ">$line<"; done < sample.txt
# vs
while IFS= read -r line; do echo ">$line<"; done < sample.txt
```